# Xpages Dojo dijit.form.numbertextbox

Tags: dojo, xpages, dijit.form, xpages-extlib

I created a number field on an xpage. However the input checking does not work properly. It accepts only numbers, which is expected behavour, but the number of entered digits is not validated. Numbers with more than 6 digits accepted which could not be possible, because of regExp \d{6}.

Here is the code on the xpage:

`<xe:djNumberTextBox id="inputTextMidasId"
                    dojoType="dijit.form.NumberTextBox"
                    value="#{complaintDocument.midasId}" javaType="short"
                    regExp="\d{6}">
                    <xe:this.constraints>
                        <xe:djNumberConstraints pattern="######">
                        </xe:djNumberConstraints>
                    </xe:this.constraints>
                </xe:djNumberTextBox>`

Can anybody tell how to make this code working? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can not explain why the regular expression doesn't work as expected.

According to the XPages Extension Library book you can use the `min` and `max` properties of `xe:djNumberConstraints` to control minimum and maximum values allowed. So perhaps you should use those instead of the regular expression?

The following does exactly what you want:

```
<xe:djNumberTextBox id="djNumberTextBox1" value="#{viewScope.test}">
    <xe:this.constraints>
        <xe:djNumberConstraints min="1" max="999999"></xe:djNumberConstraints>
    </xe:this.constraints>
</xe:djNumberTextBox>
```

**Update:**

If you write 001 in a `xe:djNumberTextBox` it will be converted to 1 when the user leaves the field. Is this what you want?

With the `xe:djValidationTextBox` you can verify the input using a regular expression. The following will do your required verification, and will allow input such as 001 to be kept in the field:

```
<xe:djValidationTextBox id="djValidationTextBox1" regExp="\d{6}"></xe:djValidationTextBox>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your code works well, however unfortunately it does not cover cases according to the regular expression \d{6} e.g. digits like 0#####, or 00#### etc.

Comment: I have updated my answer with some observations on using `xe:djValidationTextBox`

Comment: Hello, I have been thinking about this, and I accept your answers including the original, because those led me to the solution. I agree with that if I want to enter values with leading zeros, in that case I should use textbox instad of numberbox. I think the best tool here is the numberspinner.
Thank you for the help